# Rounded corners on spark buttonbar incorrect

Tags: css, air, flex4, flex-spark

I am having an issue with the spark ButtonBar. I use it on 2 places in my application with some custom CSS, but they look different in the 2 places and I have no idea why. This is a screenshot showing how I want it to look:

[image: Correct buttonbar]

This is what I don't want in the other location of my app:

[image: Incorrect buttonbar]

Notice how it seems like 2 separate buttons.

This is the CSS I use:

```
s|ButtonBar {
    chromeColor: #cfcfcf;
    color: #000000;
}

s|ButtonBarButton:up,
s|ButtonBarButton:over,
s|ButtonBarButton:down,
s|ButtonBarButton:disabled {
    chromeColor: #cfcfcf;
    color: #000000;
    cornerRadius: 4;
}

s|ButtonBarButton:upAndSelected,
s|ButtonBarButton:downAndSelected,
s|ButtonBarButton:disabledAndSelected,
s|ButtonBarButton:overAndSelected {
    chromeColor: #6D9EBA;
    cornerRadius: 4;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

I have already checked that it is 1 buttonbar, not 2 separate ones in the incorrect case. Any ideas what might be causing this?

UPDATE: I discoverd it is always is wrong when using a ButtonBar in a [NativeWindow](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/NativeWindow.html) and correct in the normal AIR application. But why? And is there a workaround?

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear enough? I am using the exact same component in 2 places in the same application, but they look different as shown in the screenshots. Since the ButtonBar component normally does this correctly, I wonder why it does not in the 2nd case.

Comment: browser compatibility?